# Parse multiline comment with nom

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I'm trying to write a nom parser that recognizes multiline comments...

```
/*
yo!
*/
```

...and consumes/discards (same thing, right?) the result:

```
use nom::{
  bytes::complete::{tag, take_until},
  error::{ErrorKind, ParseError},
  sequence::preceded,
  IResult,
};

fn multiline_comment<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    preceded(tag("/*"), take_until("*/"))(i)
}
```

This almost works. I know the take_until stops just before the `*/`, but I don't know what to do to make it include it.

```
#[test]
fn should_consume_multiline_comments() {
    assert_eq!(
        multiline_comment::<(&str, ErrorKind)>("/*abc\n\ndef*/"),
        Ok(("", "/*abc\n\ndef*/"))
    );
}
```

gives the result

```
thread 'should_consume_multiline_comments' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
left: `Ok(("*/", "abc\n\ndef"))`,
right: `Ok(("", "/*abc\n\ndef*/"))`'
```

So my question is, how do I get the full comment, including the ending `*/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you don't really want the returned string to have both preceding `/*` and closing `*/` intact - since `preceded` always discards the match from the first parser, you are never going to get that using `preceded`. I assume your main concern is ensuring that the closing `*/` is actually consumed.

For this you can use `delimited` rather than `preceded`:

```
fn multiline_comment<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    delimited(tag("/*"), is_not("*/"), tag("*/"))(i)
}
```

This passes this test:

```
assert_eq!(
    multiline_comment1::<(&str, ErrorKind)>("/*abc\n\ndef*/"),
    Ok(("", "abc\n\ndef"))
);
```

so you can be sure that the closing `*/` has been consumed.

Comment: You are correct that I didn't really want the open and closing /* ... */. I just wanted the parser to consume the comment and discard it for all I care. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to the answer from [harmic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58572819/parse-multiline-comment-with-nom/58584330#58584330)

you would want to do

```rust
fn multiline_comment<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(s: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    delimited(tag("/*"), take_until("*/"), tag("*/"))(s)
}
```

note: we are using `take_until()` instead of `is_not()`

[is_not](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/bytes/complete/fn.is_not.html) will stop when hitting any character in the pattern, meaning if you have `*` or `/` by themselves anywhere inside the comment it will fail to parse.

The original question was using `take_until` but just wanted to make it more clear for anyone who comes across this later.